# Can't use Props inside Recompse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

Am new in react I managed to add google map to my project.

The problem the google package uses recompose but when I call a props inside of it can't get my data props are empty:

my map:

```
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps"

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: this.props.lat, lng:  this.props.lat }}
  >
    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: this.props.lat, lng:  this.props.lat }} />}
  </GoogleMap>
));
```

MyMapComponent Call:

```
<MyMapComponent lat={this.state.lat} long={this.state.long}/>
```

Comment: Your `GoogeMap` component is inside of an arrow function that has `props` passed in, so you don't need the `this.` prefix, you can just to `lat: props.lat`. As an aisde: `this` will also not behave nicely because arrow functions don't have their own `this`, they inherit their parents. Not sure if just a typo in the example or not though?

Comment: and what if i wanna use it outside the arrow function? inside the lifecycle function like this one here:
https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#searchbox

Comment: You can use `this.props` inside of lifecycle, it puts any lifecycle methods you define on the actual component so that `this` is scoped correctly: https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/c830f184123eebc8ea6b8b712840fdc86a680fa2/src/packages/recompose/lifecycle.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are passed into `GoogleMap` component via `props` argument instead of bound to `this` context, here is the modified version

```
<GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={4}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng:  props.long }}  >
    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: props.lat, lng:  props.long }} />}
</GoogleMap>
```

Some another changes

- there are a few typos in example with setting longitude
- usually it is not required to specify Google Maps API version, so the
  parameter `v` could be omitted
- for the provided example the loading of additional libraries is not
  required, so `libraries`  could be also omitted

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zqqzvi)